# Word2Vec Tutorial: Tensorflow TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'

Tags: tensorflow, typeerror, word2vec

Version of Tensorflow: 1.2.1
Version of Python: 3.5
Operating System: Windows 10

Another poster has asked about this same problem on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786994/in-tensorflow-tf-nn-nce-loss-get-typeerror-input-y-of-mul-op-has-type-float), and he appears to be using code from the same Udacity Word2Vec tutorial. So, maybe I'm dense, but the code of this example is so busy and complex that I can't tell what fixed his problem.

The error occurs when I call `tf.reduce_means`:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(softmax_weights, softmax_biases, embed,
                               train_labels, num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

Right before the call to `tf.reduce_mean` the key variables have the following data types.

> train_dataset.dtype
>   >> tf.int32
>   train_labels.dtype
>   >> tf.int32
>   valid_dataset.dtype
>   >> tf.int32
>   embeddings.dtype
>   >> tf.float32_ref
>   softmax_weights.dtype
>   >> tf.float32_ref
>   softmax_biases.dtype
>   >> tf.float32_ref
>   embed.dtype
>   >> tf.float32

I tried every permutation of data type in the definitions of the variables `train_dataset.dtype`, `train_labels.dtype` and `valid_dataset.dtype`: making them all `int64`, all `float32`, all `float64`, and combinations of integer and floating point. Nothing worked. I didn't try altering the data types of `softmax_weight` and `softmax_biases`, because I'm afraid that might foul up the optimization algorithm. Don't these need to be floats to support the calculus that is done during backpropagation? (Tensorflow is often a very opaque black box with documentation that verges on completely useless, so I can suspect things but never know for sure.)

Program Flow at Time of Error:

After the call to `reduce_mean` program control transfers to `sampled_softmax_loss()` in file `nn_impl.py` which in turn calls `_compute_sampled_logits()`:

```
  logits, labels = _compute_sampled_logits(
      weights=weights,
      biases=biases,
      labels=labels,
      inputs=inputs,
      num_sampled=num_sampled,
      num_classes=num_classes,
      num_true=num_true,
      sampled_values=sampled_values,
      subtract_log_q=True,
      remove_accidental_hits=remove_accidental_hits,
      partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
      name=name)
```

At this point I check the data types of the passed-in parameters and get the following:

> weights.dtype
>   >> tf.float32_ref
>   biases.dtype
>   >> tf.float32_ref
>   labels.dtype
>   >> tf.float32
>   inputs.dtype
>   >> tf.int32

On the very next step an exception occurs, and I am thrown into the `StreamWrapper` class in file `ansitowin32.py`. Running to the end, I get the following Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    489                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 490                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    491           except TypeError as err:

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype)
    740         if ret is None:
--> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    742 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _TensorTensorConversionFunction(t, dtype, name, as_ref)
    613         "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r"
--> 614         % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
    615   return t

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("sampled_softmax_loss/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, 1, ?), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-66d378b94a16> in <module>()
     34     loss = tf.reduce_mean(
     35       tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(softmax_weights, softmax_biases, embed,
---> 36                                train_labels, num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
     37 
     38     # Optimizer.

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py in sampled_softmax_loss(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name)
   1266       remove_accidental_hits=remove_accidental_hits,
   1267       partition_strategy=partition_strategy,
-> 1268       name=name)
   1269   sampled_losses = nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,
   1270                                                             logits=logits)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py in _compute_sampled_logits(weights, biases, labels, inputs, num_sampled, num_classes, num_true, sampled_values, subtract_log_q, remove_accidental_hits, partition_strategy, name)
   1005     row_wise_dots = math_ops.multiply(
   1006         array_ops.expand_dims(inputs, 1),
-> 1007         array_ops.reshape(true_w, new_true_w_shape))
   1008     # We want the row-wise dot plus biases which yields a
   1009     # [batch_size, num_true] tensor of true_logits.

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in multiply(x, y, name)
    284 
    285 def multiply(x, y, name=None):
--> 286   return gen_math_ops._mul(x, y, name)
    287 
    288 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in _mul(x, y, name)
   1375     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `x`.
   1376   """
-> 1377   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
   1378   return result
   1379 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\aind-dog\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    524                   "%s type %s of argument '%s'." %
    525                   (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(attrs[input_arg.type_attr]).name,
--> 526                    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
    527 
    528           types = [values.dtype]

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

Here's the complete program:

```
# These are all the modules we'll be using later. 
# Make sure you can import them before proceeding further.

# %matplotlib inline

from __future__ import print_function
import collections
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from matplotlib import pylab
from six.moves import range
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

print("Working directory = %s\n" % os.getcwd())

def read_data(filename):
    """Extract the first file enclosed in a zip file as a list of words"""
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
        data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
    return data

filename = 'text8.zip'

words = read_data(filename)
print('Data size %d' % len(words))

vocabulary_size = 50000

def build_dataset(words):
    count = [['UNK', -1]]
    count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
    dictionary = dict()
    # Loop through the keys of the count collection dictionary
    # (apparently, zeroing out counts)
    for word, _ in count:
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    data = list()
    unk_count = 0  # count of unknown words
    for word in words:
        if word in dictionary:
            index = dictionary[word]
        else:
            index = 0  # dictionary['UNK']
            unk_count = unk_count + 1
        data.append(index)
    count[0][1] = unk_count
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary


data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(words)
print('Most common words (+UNK)', count[:5])
print('Sample data', data[:10])
del words  # Hint to reduce memory.

data_index = 0

def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
    global data_index
    assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
    assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
    span = 2 * skip_window + 1 # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
    buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
    for _ in range(span):
        buffer.append(data[data_index])
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
    for i in range(batch_size // num_skips):
        target = skip_window  # target label at the center of the buffer
        targets_to_avoid = [ skip_window ]
        for j in range(num_skips):
            while target in targets_to_avoid:
                target = random.randint(0, span - 1)
            targets_to_avoid.append(target)
            batch[i * num_skips + j] = buffer[skip_window]
            labels[i * num_skips + j, 0] = buffer[target]
        buffer.append(data[data_index])
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
    return batch, labels

print('data:', [reverse_dictionary[di] for di in data[:8]])

for num_skips, skip_window in [(2, 1), (4, 2)]:
    data_index = 0
    batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=num_skips, skip_window=skip_window)
    print('\nwith num_skips = %d and skip_window = %d:' % (num_skips, skip_window))
    print('    batch:', [reverse_dictionary[bi] for bi in batch])
    print('    labels:', [reverse_dictionary[li] for li in labels.reshape(8)])

batch_size = 128
embedding_size = 128  # Dimension of the embedding vector.
skip_window = 1  # How many words to consider left and right.
num_skips = 2  # How many times to reuse an input to generate a label.
# We pick a random validation set to sample nearest neighbors. here we limit the
# validation samples to the words that have a low numeric ID, which by
# construction are also the most frequent.
valid_size = 16  # Random set of words to evaluate similarity on.
valid_window = 100  # Only pick dev samples in the head of the distribution.
valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(valid_window), valid_size))
num_sampled = 64  # Number of negative examples to sample.

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Input data.
    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
    valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

    # Variables.
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    softmax_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
    softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

    # Model.
    # Look up embeddings for inputs.
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
    # Compute the softmax loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(softmax_weights, softmax_biases, embed,
                                   train_labels, num_sampled, vocabulary_size))

    # Optimizer.
    # Note: The optimizer will optimize the softmax_weights AND the embeddings.
    # This is because the embeddings are defined as a variable quantity and the
    # optimizer's `minimize` method will by default modify all variable quantities
    # that contribute to the tensor it is passed.
    # See docs on `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize()` for more details.
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

    # Compute the similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
    # We use the cosine distance:
    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
    valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
        normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
    similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it looks like that two parameters that are passed on to the loss function are swapped around. 
If you look at the tensorflow description for 'sample_softmax_loss' (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss):

```
sampled_softmax_loss(
    weights,
    biases,
    labels,
    inputs,
    num_sampled,
    num_classes,
    num_true=1,
    sampled_values=None,
    remove_accidental_hits=True,
    partition_strategy='mod',
    name='sampled_softmax_loss'
)
```

The third expected parameter is 'labels' and the fourth 'inputs'. In the supplied code, these two parameters seem to have been switched around. I'm a bit puzzled how this is possible. Maybe this used to be different in an older version of TF. Anyway, swapping those two parameters around will solve the problem.